# Virtuemart Joomla menu highlights wrong item

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a Virtuemart 1.1.7a install on Joomla 1.5. We're using a Joomla menu as the shop side menu. Not every category is listed in this menu (only the 'parent' categories, no subcategories). When users navigate to a sub category (i.e one not in the list) it highlights the wrong category from the side menu. You can see this on:

http://www.lochlomond-trossachs.org/books.html

and selecting 'Local Authors'. Then menu item 'Postcards' is highlighted on the left.

It would be preferable to either a) highlight no category or b) highlight 'Books' (which is the parent category of 'Local Authors').

I've had a look on the VM forums and web at large for issues with Joomla menus in VM, but the vast majority of results relate to an earlier problem regarding Itemids loading the wrong products ,but this is not the case here. Simply fixing the highlight would suffice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using Joomla menus for VM categories just doesn't really work that well. Replaced Joomla menu with VM menu (i.e. mod_virtuemart), and styled to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, virtuemart has issues with this. Unless you want to dive into the Virtuemart code (which can take you a long time to find the  code dealing with the Itemid), I would recomment to add extra menu-items under the category that is it's parent. If you don't want these to be visible, you can go to the menu module and set the depth of the menu. The right parent would now be highlighted, because it has a child in it's roots.

Comment: Gave this a shot, creating menu items for each subcat and then setting the depth to 1 (main cats only). Still highlights wrong item when inside a subcategory, which is frustrating. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might help: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=70482.0

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see "Local Authors", but I saw the problem with Gifts (when I click on Gift, and then on Mugs, for example, I have postcards highlighted). I believe the problem is either in your template or in your data itself.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Not much to go on, 'template' + 'data' = 'site'... Would really appreciate the assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remake all the menu buttons as in delete and create new ones.